# Assertion failure and crash on JavaFx application (MacOS)

Tags: macos, javafx, scene, assertion, stage

I made this JavaFX application which crashes everytime I use it for an undefined time, and the only error it gives is this one:

```
    java[1133:134799] unrecognized type is 4294967295
    java[1133:134799] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.10.106/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
    java[1133:134799] unrecognized type is 4294967295
    java[1133:134799] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.10.106/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
    java[1133:134799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: _type > 0 && _type <= kCGSLastEventType'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37e04e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff63e5b720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37e1fab2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3a1c3d1d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff352ac029 -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:] + 3272
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff355ff74c +[NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:] + 120
    6   libglass.dylib                      0x000000011c0086fb listenTouchEvents + 59
    7   SkyLight                            0x00007fff5df1141e _ZL19processEventTapDataPvjjjPhj + 148
    8   SkyLight                            0x00007fff5de0fc9e _XPostEventTapData + 278
    9   SkyLight                            0x00007fff5df1132c _ZL22eventTapMessageHandlerP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 132
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37d657cf __CFMachPortPerform + 282
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37d656a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37d65607 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 527
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37d4d689 __CFRunLoopRun + 2574
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37d4ca28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 463
    15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff36fe5b35 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 293
    16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff36fe5774 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 371
    17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff36fe55e8 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff352a1eb7 _DPSNextEvent + 997
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff352a0c56 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1362
    20  libglass.dylib                      0x000000011bff646c +[GlassApplication enterNestedEventLoopWithEnv:] + 172
    21  libglass.dylib                      0x000000011bff6eaa Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacApplication__1enterNestedEventLoopImpl + 74
    22  ???                                 0x0000000106546667 0x0 + 4401161831
    23  ???                                 0x0000000106536040 0x0 + 4401094720
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Java Result: 134
```

I tried the same app on Windows and Linux and it works perfectly, so I don't understand if on MacOs I need to add or change something to my code. This is the main of my app:

```
public class MailBox extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader listLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lista.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menubar.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader textareaLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textarea.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader fieldLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textfield.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader buttonLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("button.fxml"));

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(listLoader.load(), textareaLoader.load(), fieldLoader.load(), menuLoader.load(), buttonLoader.load());

    ListController listController = listLoader.getController();
    MenuBarController menuController = menuLoader.getController();
    TextAreaController textareaController = textareaLoader.getController();
    TextFieldController fieldController = fieldLoader.getController();
    ButtonController buttonController = buttonLoader.getController();

    DataModel model = new DataModel();
    listController.initModel(model);
    menuController.initModel(model);
    textareaController.initModel(model);
    fieldController.initModel(model);
    buttonController.initModel(model);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 603, 403);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

And here is a part of my Panel controller where I declare another stage:

```
public class PanelController {

@FXML
private TextField dest;
@FXML
private TextField obj;
@FXML
private TextArea testo;
@FXML
private Button invia;

private DataModel model;

public void initModel(DataModel model) {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model;
}

public void initRispondi(DataModel model) {
    dest.setText(model.currentEmailProperty().getValue().getMittente());
    dest.setDisable(true);
}

public void initReplyAll(DataModel model) {
    final ObservableList<Email> elenco = model.getEmailList();
    String s = "";
    for (Email mail : elenco) {
        s+=""+mail.MittenteProperty().getValue()+"; ";
    }
    dest.setText(s);
    dest.setDisable(true);
}

public void initForward(DataModel model) {
    obj.setText(model.currentEmailProperty().getValue().getOggetto());
    testo.setText(model.currentEmailProperty().getValue().getTesto());
}

@FXML
public void scrivi() throws IOException {
    String[] da_inv = new String[4];
    da_inv[0] = dest.getText();
    da_inv[1] = model.getAccountName();
    da_inv[2] = obj.getText();
    da_inv[3] = testo.getText();
    boolean ok = true;
    for (int i=0; i<4 && ok; i++) {
        if (da_inv[i].length()<1)
            ok = false;
    }
    if (!ok)
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Compila tutti i campi!").showAndWait();
    else {
        model.writeMail(da_inv);
        Window stage = dest.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.hide();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javafx FileChooser Mac OS NSInternalInconsistencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754862/javafx-filechooser-mac-os-nsinternalinconsistencyexception)

Comment: Have a look on [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172847). Only few minutes to find it. (And the repeateadly Escape key tap is not the only reason of this bug)

Comment: @Pagbo No, it didn't solve my problem and the error is different.

Comment: The error of the second link is the same and incriminate the JDK... What's your JDK version ?

Comment: @Pagbo This is the current version Java (I found it by typing java -version on the terminal): `java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)`

Comment: I installed the Java SE Development Kit 8u192 found on this link but nothing changed [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Answer (score 0):

Multiples java versions are installed on your PC, Delete the one that is not compatible with scene builder, for me, I have scene builder 8.5.0 and two versions of java 8 and 11, so the java 11 was causing the problem then I deleted it and scene builder now is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I upgraded from version 17.0.2 to 21.02 of the JavaFX library and the issue was solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```